# nodejs client s3 getSignedUrl gives Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm generating a presigned url to an s3 bucket using the following code

```
  const presignedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: config.parsedResumeDestination,
    Key: tmpKey,
    Expires: 60 * 60 * 60 // 1 hour
  });
```

However when I just copy past the generated url on the browser I get the following error

`Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4`

I saw the following solution [How to generate AWS S3 pre-signed URL using signature version 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369427/how-to-generate-aws-s3-pre-signed-url-using-signature-version-4), however the nodejs client for aws does not seem to have this property.  Can someone please tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

When you construct the s3 service object, pass in a `signatureVersion`.

Here is one way to do it:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  ...credentials
})
```

There are lots of options when constructing AWS service objects and they are mostly universal:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#constructor-property